# Htaccess Redirect not working in wordpress with WHMCS-WP Integration

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WHMCS-WP Integrator and want to customize URLs, I have rewrite URL in wordpress .htaccess file but its not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^billing/client-area/$ /billing/?whmcsportal%5Bpage%5D=whmcs%3A%2F%2Fwww.thesmarttech.com%2Fclientarea.php
</IfModule>
```

my current URL is

```
http://www.thesmarttech.com/test/billing/?whmcsportal%5Bpage%5D=whmcs%3A%2F%2Fwww.thesmarttech.com%2F
```

and i want to rewite it to

```
http://www.thesmarttech.com/test/billing/client-area/
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You need to remove the leading slash in your rule's target. It's going to get interpreted as an absolute URL-path and the `/test/` URI base won't be used
2. You have to escape (using a backslash) your `%`'s in the target. Mod_rewrite's going to interpret those as backreferences
3. You need to use the `NE` flag, so that the `%`'s don't get encoded:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^billing/client-area/$ billing/?whmcsportal\%5Bpage\%5D=whmcs\%3A\%2F\%2Fwww.thesmarttech.com\%2Fclientarea.php [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Also, make sure those rules are in the htaccess file in the `/test/` directory.

Comment: still it is not working... its giving page not found error. You can visit http://www.thesmarttech.com/test/billing/client-area/ to view the error

Comment: when i write RewriteRule ^billing/client-area/$ billing/?whmcsportal\%5Bpage\%5D=whmcs\%3A\%2F\%2Fwww.thesmarttech.com\%2Fclientarea.php [R=301,L,NE], it works correctly but when i remove R=301 it give 404 error